# Not able to set terminal title with Django runserver

Tags: python, django, bash

I am using the following `set-title` function from this post on [How to rename terminal tab title in gnome-terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186167/20895)

```
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$@\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

I have the following in my `.env` file

```
set-title SERVER
python manage.py runserver
```

I am running the above as follows:

```
. .env
```

The problem is that it doesn't work when `python manage.py runserver` is present. But when I kill the current running server instance, it changes the title automatically to what I want.

Why is the above behaviour happening when clearly `set-title` should execute first.

Comment: It seems that the title is refreshed only after the script is sourced. add sleep after the call to set-title and you see that it refreshed only after that

Comment: @eran Yeah you're right! Any other way to do it immediately??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually have script that launches **new** gnome terminal using the `gnome-terminal` command, optionally with several tabs (for example, if I need tow django servers to run in parallel, or django server and DB console).

The drawback is that this is new terminal, however, if you need several tabs it can start you fresh new terminal with all your tabs - you just need to write your script once.

Man page is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html)

```
    gnome-terminal --tab -t django1 --working-directory="dir1" -e "python manage.py runserver 8000" \
                   --tab -t django2 --working-directory="dir2" -e "python manage.py runserver 8002"
```